# Последовательность загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

```html
<p>Начало документа...</p>
<script>
  alert('Привет, Мир!');
</script>

<p>...Конец документа</p>
```

Есть вот такой скрипт. По идее при загрузке страницы должен выводиться первый параграф, потом алерт, а потом второй параграф. Но в chrome сначала выводится алерт. Почему так?

P.S. С командой 'use strict' все последовательно.

Comment: `alert()` всегда будет первым так как он выше по приоритету

Comment: А где приоритеты посмотреть можно?

Comment: В любом учебнике по JavaScript

Comment: Почему тогда в другом браузере выполняется все по порядку без приоритетов?

Comment: 1. Написал выше. 2. Тогда в скрипте укажите явно, чтоб он работал только после загрузки всего DOM. Используйте `DOMContentLoaded` если в JS